# How should I update my LinkedIn acct, that I haven't used in years, that I'm no longer with my last employer, and looking for work?

Tags: job-search, termination, linkedin, social-media, severance

Background: I was offered/given an acceptable severance package to leave, so I did. The regional manager & HR manager said they would confirm with prospective employers my start / end dates and my title, but wouldn't give me any reference after I asked. My last day with the employer is almost a month ago.

I recently found the manager's name on two recent LinkedIn emails in my blocked folder, before and after I left. I didn't open the emails so I don't know if the manager was trying to connect or more likely just looking if my account reflects my separation from the company.

I find all the LinkedIn emails I used to receive annoying so blocked it many years ago and haven't used it since starting with my last employer.

Question: What should I do with my LinkedIn account? Delete it or update it? If update, how should I show this change in my last posted position of almost 20 years? What's normal for stating I retired from the company and pivoting from my last position and looking for work in QA/QC in the same or related industry?

Relevance: I'm working with a recruiter who says deleting my LinkedIn won't kill my career (I'm within 5 years of retiring). Updating my account may attract prospective employers in my specific engineering industry.

Comment: You have that many years but no professional network to leverage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As annoying as LinkedIn is, I found it invaluable during my job hunt. I got more interviews from recruiters contacting me through LinkedIn than from actual job applications. Refresh it the same way you would a resume. One you get hired, temporarily deactivate until you need it again. That's what I do, because I hate getting tons of random emails from it.

As for the actual content you should update, LinkedIn has a bunch of "skills" and keywords you should use which help recruiters looking for specific people. Add as many of those as are relevant.

For your previous roles, you can put in information much like a resume with bullet points of responsibilities, projects, etc.